# What is probability that area of rectangle is more than $0.5$, if sides are Uniform Random variables between $0$ and $1$?

Tags: probability

If we call the side length $x$ then the area will be $x^2$ and it seems that we need $x^2 > 0.5$. So $x > \sqrt{0.5}$ which comes out to be $0.707$. But I realized this is a wrong method.

Can somebody please help me out to solve this question?

Comment: You're assuming the shape is a square; the problem seems to suggest that the width and height of the shape are independent.

Comment: @angryavian Yes you are right. Both sides are independent random variables.

Comment: Please edit the question, so that the question is inserted also in the text and reflects the above comment. (Do we have a rectangle or a square? Ar the side length also independent?) Please provide more context to the question. Please show a real attempt to solve the issue. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the values of $x$ and $y$ in your stated range where the product is $x y > .5$.

Can you calculate the area in parameter space?

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do we find that particular area? I am not getting any intuition about how to calculate the shaded area?

Comment: Straightforward integration.

Comment: Thank you sir!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Choose the length (presumably uniformly) between $0$ and $1$ on the $x$-axis. Choose the width (independently) on the $y$-axis. Find the area of the part of the unit square that satisfies your  restriction on the area of the rectangle.

Comment: Can you please give me some more intuition how to find that area? As visualized  in another answer.

Comment: Elementary calculus will find the area in the unit square over that hyperbola.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. I didn't think that at first.